# Android AlertDialog not centering/scaling vertically

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm building an AlertDialog that contains a custom View like so:

```java
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_INTRO:
            // setup the dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            View inflatedLayout = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.intro, null);
            builder.setView(inflatedLayout);

            // return the dialog
            return builder.create();
    }

    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

And the layout XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:shrinkColumns="1">
    
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/intro_TextView_title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/intro_title"
                android:textSize="22sp" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </TableRow>
    
        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
                android:paddingTop="2dip"
                android:src="@drawable/intro_add" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/intro_TextView_add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:text="@string/intro_add" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- ... -->

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

That gives me a dialog that looks something like this (details blurred, sorry):

[image: blurred AlertDialog screenshot]

The problem is that big gap at the top (above the dialog). Is there anything I can do to either get rid of it or make the bottom have a similar gap?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug (kinda). You have to just implement your own Dialog to make it work right.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is described here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11824. The AlertDialog is reserving space for the title/icon panel even where there is neither a title nor an icon.

The fix is, I think, quite simple: it should set the top panel layout to GONE, just as it does for the button panel in the event of there being no buttons. Until that's done, the only workaround is to implement your own Dialog subclass.